# Using pnpjs 8.15 in SPFx - get() is not a function

Tags: spfx, pnp-js

New to pnpjs, using 8.15.0 trying to get a list of lists in a SPFx.

I'm getting error: TypeError: this.sp.web.lists.get is not a function. I have list item updates working in this same ts file. Assuming I am missing an import, can anyone advise.

```
import { spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp"; //"@pnp/sp/presets/all" //
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import "@pnp/sp/files";
import "@pnp/sp/folders";
import { IField, IFieldAddResult, FieldTypes, IFieldInfo } from "@pnp/sp/fields/types";
import "@pnp/sp/lists/web";
import "@pnp/sp/fields";
import "@pnp/sp/items/get-all";
import {Web, IWeb} from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
```

...

```
const lists: any[] = await sp.web.lists.filter('Hidden eq false').get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.get()` since version 3 as far as I remember:

```
const lists: any[] = await sp.web.lists.filter('Hidden eq false')();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at old documents

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `get` with the latest versions of the PnP JS library.

You can just use `()` instead of `get()`.

You can follow the official PnP JS documentation for more information and examples: [@pnp/sp/lists](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/lists/)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at old documents